# LINQ filter nullable datetime with matching params?

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

I need to filter my nullable datetime by day month and year.

I currently trying to do it by using string comparisons. I have this in where statement in linq:

```
DOB.ToString().StartsWith("2/25/19") || DOB == null
```

But its not working. I know its because the server doesnt store the date like that, but Im unsure as to how it is storing it, and how can I retrieve it and do the comparison.

I REALLY need this to happen on the database. I cant get everything and filter in the server.

I just want linq to filter dates by day, month, and year

Any help or pointers are appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for all records with DOB in 20th century on Feb 25? There are other ways to achieve this. How would you do this on the DB side? Are you using a stored procedure?

Comment: You should probably be using a DateTime method to compare the values instead of turning it into a string. There is a property `Date` on `DateTime` that might help you...

Comment: What I want is to be able to write "2" and get all DOB that have a month of 2-february. or write 2/25 and get all DOB whose day is 25 and month is february.

Comment: When you say "write '2' ", do you mean write in your code or UI? Can you post some context for your question? Perhaps entire LINQ query.

Comment: This won't help much but you'll have problems with october to december monthes when searching for january. Lets me think a better path has to be found...

Comment: I updated the question, what @TomDoesCode sounds like it could work.

Comment: @Floremin yes all the DOB on the 20th century.

Comment: @xum59 thats okay, thats what I want. jan oct nov dec, since they start with 1 on their month. Just like a starts with.

Comment: does your filter input have a special format ? e.g. 1 TextBox for each date part or a single TB with a particular string format ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this (updated to include optional date components):

```
int? month = 2;
int? day = 25;
int? century = 19; // actual century minus one

// other LINQ here
.Where(x => x.DOB == null 
    || ((month == null || x.DOB.Month = month)
     && (day == null || x.DOB.Day = day)
     && (century == null || x.DOB.Year / 100 == century)));
```

Comment: this looks good, but what If I dont specify a year? or i dont specify a year and month?, would the linq statement became huge?

Comment: I update the answer to consider optional date components.

Comment: I ended up doing (DOB.Value.Date.Month.ToString() + "/" + DOB.Value.Date.Day.ToString() + "/" + DOB.Value.Date.Year.ToString()).StartsWith("2/25/19") || DOB == null
but your answer gave me the insight I needed. thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter by day, month, year, use the example code below:

```
    DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;
    Console.WriteLine(dateTime.Day);
    Console.WriteLine(dateTime.Month);
    Console.WriteLine(dateTime.Year);
```

You can get those value from `DateTime` object. Then, you can apply filter on it.

After reading the comment, I got your point.

For example, you enter a string like this:

```
string search = "2/25/2015";
```

Now, you want to extract the value of the string to perform filter, right? Simply do:

```
string[] values = search.Split('/');
```

Then, the `values` would be `[2, 25, 2015]`. First element is month, second is day, third is year, that depends on how you define the format.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
context.Entities.Where(e => e.Date != null && e.Date.Day == 15)
```

you can use `DateTime.Day`, `DateTime.Month`, `DateTime.Year` and the logical operators `&&` and `||` to filter as you see fit. You must however check for *nullity* first or you may end up with `NullExceptions`

Comment: I need nulls and matching items.

Comment: @luisluix you can change the conditions to `e.Date == null || ...)`. That will short-circuit if the date is actually `null`